# Delete folder from gallery but images are still there

Tags: android, file, android-gallery

Hello I am attempting to delete an entire folder from the gallery using this code

```
public void delete(View view)
{
    deleteDirectory(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Dir"));
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

}

public static boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
    if( path.exists() ) {
      File[] files = path.listFiles();
      if (files == null) {
          return true;
      }
      for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
         if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
           deleteDirectory(files[i]);
         }
         else {
           files[i].delete();
         }
      }
    }

    return( path.delete() );
  }
```

When I browse the sd card all the images are gone, however the images are still appearing in the gallery except for the image most recently taken

Comment: that's because your gallery doesn't know the images are gone.

Comment: is there a way I can inform the gallery they are gone?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using this instead of the other `sendBroadcast`

`sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"Dir"))));`